# Solve: $(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy=0$ using $Mx-Ny$ method of reducing to exact differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using $Mx-Ny$ method for reducing to exact differential equations (for which the criteria is satisfied here), it gets simplified to $\frac{3dx}{2x}+\frac{dy}{2y}-a\frac{ydx+xdy}{x^2}=0$. This is where I get stuck at having to find integral of $\frac{ydx+xdy}{x^2}$. Here, $Mx-Ny=2x^2y$.

Now I know this can be solved through various other methods. But I am trying to figure out if I can solve using $Mx-Ny$ method. But I have no idea of how to solve $\frac{ydx+xdy}{x^2}$ if it is even possible?

**Edit**: Realizing from @Oscar Lanzi's answer that $\frac{ydx+xdy}{x^2}$ is not integrable. Is there any other rearrangement of $\frac{(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy}{2x^2y}=0$ that is easily integrable?

**Answer**: $x^2y(x-ay)=c$

Comment: you say you want to solve: $$\int\frac{ydx+xdy}{x^2}$$ ?

Comment: You are getting confused by how you grouped together the terms; all you want to do is to find $\int \frac{M}{Mx-Ny} dx$ in terms of an unknown function $f(y)$, differentiate with respect to $y$, and set the result equal to $\frac{N}{Mx-Ny}$ to solve for $f'$. Then integrate $f$ to finish. So it looks like you need $\int \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{x} - 2a \frac{y}{x^2} dx$ which seems straightforward enough to find.

Comment: Remember that in the end, once the equation has been transformed to be exact, all you're doing is finding a potential function for a conservative vector field.

Comment: @Ian in your first comment after differentiating with respect to y, do I equate it to $\frac{N}{Mx-Ny}$ or its derivative with respect to x? Also how do I integrate the $-a\frac{y}{x^2}dx$ term?

Comment: $\int \frac{M}{Mx-Ny} dx = f(x,y) + g(y)$, where $f(x,y)$ is an explicit function and $g(y)$ is an unknown function. This whole thing is your potential function $F(x,y)$, which (if you did it right) has $\frac{M}{Mx-Ny}$ as its $x$ partial. You hope that it is possible to select $g$ such that it also has $\frac{N}{Mx-Ny}$ as its $y$ partial. So you differentiate and get $f_y(x,y) + g'(y)$ and set that equal to $\frac{N}{Mx-Ny}$ and then solve for $g'$. If it worked, the thing you get is only a function of $y$, which you then integrate with respect to $y$ to get $g$.

Comment: I followed that completely. But I only have one issue in finding $f(x,y)$. How do I integrate ${-a\frac{y}{x^2}dx}$? I think I only have to take partial integral of it here, right? So the y term should not matter.

Comment: Is $f(x,y)=\frac{3}{2}logx + a\frac{y}{x}$? But knowing that the answer for this is $x^2y(x-ay)=c$. I tried solving with this $f(x,y)$ but I get g(x,y) instead of g(y).

Comment: I don't think the Mx-Ny method is applicable here in the first place because if you divide $M$ by $y$ you get $3x-2ay$ which is not a function of $xy$. Are you sure you even copied the problem correctly?

Comment: Indeed it would work properly if the $y$ that is squared in $M$ is the other one, and if $y$ is squared instead of $x$ in $N$. Seems like an easy transcription error to make...

Comment: In fact it is not copied correctly.  By differentiating the quoted solution and multiplying by a factor they threw in to make the equation not exact (you have to find the integrating factor that undoes that), I actually get $(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2a\color{red}{x}y)dy=0$.

Comment: Which still isn't in the right form for this Mx-Ny method.

Comment: Right @ian, but the correct form admits an integrating factor much easier to identify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't stated correctly. If you reverse engineer the solution you find that its $M$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^2 y(x-ay)=2xy(x-ay)+x^2 y = 3x^2y - 2axy^2$ and its $N$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} x^2 y(x-ay)=x^2(x-ay)-ax^2y=x^3-2ax^2 y$. Thus, apparently the writer of the question divided the exact equation:

$$(3x^2 y - 2axy^2) dx + (x^3-2ax^2 y) dy = 0$$

by $x$ which results in

$$(3xy - 2ay^2) dx + (x^2-2axy) dy = 0.$$

This problem is not in the correct form to use the "Mx-Ny method" since for instance $3xy-2ay^2$ is not of the form $yf(xy)$. Instead if you try to work from scratch you arrive at the PDE

$$\mu_y (3xy-2ay^2) + \mu(3x-4ay) = \mu_x (x^2-2axy) + \mu(2x-2ay).$$

This simplifies to

$$\mu_y(3xy-2ay^2) + \mu(x-2ay) = \mu_x (x^2-2axy).$$

You see now that the coefficient on $\mu$ and the coefficient on $\mu_x$ only differ by a factor which is a function of $x$, which means you can assume $\mu_y=0$ and get

$$\mu = x \mu_x.$$

Thus $\mu=x$ is an admissible integrating factor (as we'd expect from how the reverse engineering went).

Comment: Thanks, @Ian. I'll keep in mind to post the question correctly, so that I don't trouble the community too much. Also, since I am studying from pdf of handwritten notes, I mistook $f(xy)$ as $f(x,y)$. Thanks, for making me realize the gap in my understanding.